# Splitting Emails with MIME::Parser

Tags: perl, email, mime

I got handed 4GB of emails concatenated into a single file and the suggestion that MIME::Parser could split the individual emails back out again.  All my attempts to date end up with the parser just copying the original file without extracting any of the emails.  So: Is this even something that MIME::Parser can handle?  My code is very basic:

```
my $file = IO::File->new("somefile", O_RDONLY);
my $parser = new MIME::Parser;
$parser->output_dir("somedir");
my $entity = $parser->parse($file);
$file->close;
```

Below is a link to sample date that some have requested.  **This is all SPAM and phishing emails.  DO NOT CLICK ANY OF THE LINKS.**  Enjoy: [Pastbin of 4KB of emails.](http://pastebin.com/pqNcfP4N)

Comment: show some of your file?  maybe the first few lines and last few lines of the first and second messages?

Comment: Is this a one time thing? If so, you may be better off doing it by hand. If not, what software puts it in this format?

Comment: By hand isn't feasible.  The source file is 4GB in size so I anticipate on the order of 300,000+ emails.

Comment: Looking at the provided data, this isn't any format at all, it is just emails concatenated together - which means there is no reliable way to split them apart again.  The best you are going to be able to do is look for Received: with as strict a pattern as possible (which will mess up any emails that contain that pattern as part of the content and leave any headers that might precede received as part of the previous message)

Comment: @ysth: I did make an attend at splitting on "Received: from " last night.  It works to an extent but eventually grinds to a halt.  I'll try to improve the regex to see if that helps.  I'm hesitant to keep bugging the source of the data because they're taking time out of their work day to supply the data.  But that might be the only solution.

Answer (score 2):

[MIME::Parser](https://metacpan.org/pod/MIME::Parser) is for reading a single Mail to get the attachments etc. It can be used to extract mails which are attached inside another mail as `message/rfc822`, but is is not intended to extract mails from some kind of archive with lots of mails in it concatenated.

It is not clear what format your single file with mails has. But if it comes from a UNIX system or from a Thunderbird installation it might simply be in the classical [Mbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mbox) format and there are several tools to split Mbox files into separate messages. Apart from [several perl modules](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=mbox&mode=all) there are also other tools like `git-mailsplit` which help you extract the mails from Mbox-format.

Comment: Apparently the file is not in the Mbox format.  I used Mail::Mbox::MessageParser but I get the "Not a mailbox" error.

Comment: So you ask us to help getting mails from some unknown format without even describing the format or giving an example. I don't think we can help you much then.

Comment: All of the sample emails are malicious.  I copied some to Pastebin as per the above link.